# How to remove charset=utf-8 in a Content-Type header, generated by spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to send an mp4 file as a response body in spring-boot. I've tried setting the `Content-Type` header to `video/mp4` using the following methods:

1. A RequestMapping annotation parameter:

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/movie.mp4", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "video/mp4")
   ```
2. Manually setting a header value via `HttpHeaders`, passed to return `ResponseEntity`.

Each time the resulting header is as follows:

```
Content-Type:video/mp4; charset=UTF-8
```

How do I get rid of the `charset=UTF-8` postfix?

Comment: How about setting the value you prefer and thereby stopping spring boot from appending it automagically ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It took some debugging, but I found that `HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration` sets `spring.http.encoding.force=true`. If you set this to false in your `application.properties`, the charset will be omitted.

Comment: `spring.http.encoding.force=false` removes charset from header