# JSON encoding using produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"} and ObjectMapper

Tags: json, spring-boot

I am trying to develop a microservice using Spring MVC and Spring Boot. In my service I am giving result back as JSON encoded format. Currently I added action like:

```
@RequestMapping("/checkUsers")
    public String checkLogin() throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Users> useObj = (List<Users>) userRepo.findAll();
        return(mapper.writeValueAsString(useObj));
    }
```

And now I found the other options through the following method

```
produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
```

Here I am not sure which method is properly using for encoding the data into JSON format in Spring. How can I proceed?

Comment: see
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39788503/spring-restcontroller-produces-charset-utf-8/39794195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don’t you just use 
         ResponseEntity

And return 
         `new   ResponseEntity<String>(“your    message”, HttpStatus.OK);`

Answer (score 3):

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "my/random/uri", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
```

Here **produces** attribute inside my [@RequestMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces--) annotation is the producible media types of the mapped request. The format is a single media type or a sequence of media types, with a request only mapped if mentioned one matches one of these media types. and here, my @RequestMapping annotation is already serving my purpose of encoding.

Now somewhere from Spring Boot documentation:

> Spring Boot is a brand new framework  designed to simplify the bootstrapping and development of a new Spring
>   application. The framework takes an opinionated approach to
>   configuration, freeing developers from the need to define boilerplate
>   configuration.

Please don't kill the purpose of Spring Boot. :)

Additionally, I would suggest you use **org.springframework.http.MediaType** class. It has got all encoding types you'll ever require. Happy coding.

Please let me know if you face any difficulty while going with suggested approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77084076/type-error-application-json-in-spring-boot-3-1-controller?noredirect=1#comment135895901_77084076 similar issue if you know answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you use @RestController on your controller, all request mappings will produce application/json by default.

Also, there is no need to to the object mapping yourself, just return the object without mapping and let Spring/Jackson do its thing.

```
@RestController
public class UsersController {
    // @RequestMapping("/checkUsers")
    // There is an even simpler and more concise
    @GetMapping("/checkUsers")
    public List<User> checkLogin() throws JsonProcessingException { 
        return userRepo.findAll(); 
    }
}
```