# Why would spring overwrite Content-Type in header?

Tags: spring, content-type

After I set http header in `Controller` in such way:

```
@Controller
@Slf4j
public class PlayerController {    
    @ModelAttribute
    public void setVaryResponseHeader(HttpServletResponse response) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl");
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/live/timeshift.m3u8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String playbackLive(@RequestParam(value = "delay") Integer delay) {
        ....
    }
}
```

then later Spring overwrite it to plain text, callstack here:

```
writeWithMessageConverters:184, AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation)
handleReturnValue:174, RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor (org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation)
handleReturnValue:81, HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite (org.springframework.web.method.support)
......
run:624, ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker (java.util.concurrent)
run:61, TaskThread$WrappingRunnable (org.apache.tomcat.util.threads)
run:748, Thread (java.lang)
```

why would spring do that? it's so hard to understand, I think user customized logic has higher priority, spring should not make decision automatically.

actually, I think the question has enough explanation, but SO thinks there is mostly code, asking to add more detail, what can I do, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the controller and the method calling `setVaryResponseHeader`.

Comment: @StavShamir Hi, it is annotated with ModelAttribute and was invoked by SpringFramework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **TL;DR**

#### Why and how spring overwrite the ContentType in header?

There is a default spring configuration, based on 3 strategies which select the content type to be returned. The configuration could be modified.

#### Customising all the content-type header responses from all the controllers

There are two ways of customising the content-type header negotiation configuration for all the responses, by XML configuration and another via Annotation driven configuration.

#### Customising the content-type header value for certain URLs

On very same configuration, there is a way of injection a customised strategy for choosing which URLs should be affected by the rule of changing the content-type header.

#### On Spring Boot

Thankfully, on spring boot adding the produce attribute on the  @RequestMapping anotation of the controller and also changing a property would be enough for getting the desire behaviour:

- @RequestMapping(value = "/live/timeshift.m3u8", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
- Property - > *spring.http.encoding.enabled* set to true

---

## **Long Answer**

## Why and how spring overwrite the ContentType in header?

In Spring MVC there are three options to determine the media type of a request:

1. URL suffixes (extensions) in the request (like .xml/.json)
2. URL parameter in the request (like ?format=json)
3. Accept header in the request done to your controller method

On this very order Spring negotiate the content-type header response and the body response format, and if none of these are enabled, we can specify a fallback to a default content type.

## Customising all the content-type header responses from all the controllers

So for customising this behavior we should provide a fallback default content type and deactivate the three strategies described above. There are two approaches for acomplishing it, using XML configuration or annotation configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
    favorParameter(false).
    ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
    useJaf(false).
    defaultContentType("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl");
  }
}
```

Or the XML configuration

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
  class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="false"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl"/>
    <property name="useJaf" value="false" />
</bean>
```

## Customising the content-type header value for certain URLs

Another custom solution would be create your own @DefaultContentType annotation. Overrinding RequestMappingHandlerMapping#getCustomMethodCondition which checks for the annotation@DefaultContentType on the  method. The custom condition would always match but in the compareTo, it would prioritize methods that have the annotation, over those that don't.

I would do the above solution if you need to use it a lot of times.

For a one off occurrence, you could plug in a custom defaultContentTypeStrategy via ContentNegotiationConfigurer that checks for a specific URL and returns a preferred media type like:

```
public class MyCustomContentNegotiationStrategy implements ContentNegotiationStrategy {

  @Override
  public List<MediaType> resolveMediaTypes (final NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest)
            throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
      final List<MediaType> mediaTypes = new ArrayList<>();
      final String url =((ServletWebRequest)request).getRequest().getRequestURI().toString();
      final String yourUrlpatternString = ".*http://.*";

      final Pattern yourUrlPattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
      final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

     if(matcher.matches()) {
          mediaTypes.add("application/vnd.apple.mpegurl");
      return mediaTypes;
  }
}
```

Then, add your custom strategy via configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MyWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation (ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.defaultContentTypeStrategy(new MyCustomContentNegotiationStrategy());
  }
}
```

## On Spring Boot

Finally, if you're using spring boot, as @StavShamir has suggested, on answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62422889/3346298, there are a bunch of common application properties which could be helpful on this case:

```
# HTTP encoding (HttpEncodingProperties)
# Charset of HTTP requests and responses. Added to the "Content-Type" header if not set explicitly.
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8 
# Whether to enable http encoding support.
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true 
# Whether to force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests and responses.
spring.http.encoding.force= 
# Whether to force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP requests. Defaults to true when "force" has not been 
spring.http.encoding.force-request= specified.
# Whether to force the encoding to the configured charset on HTTP responses.
spring.http.encoding.force-response= 
# Locale in which to encode mapping.
spring.http.encoding.mapping=
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

On this very case, the *spring.http.encoding.enabled* property set to true and using the
argument produces argument on @RequestMapping annotation would work:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/live/timeshift.m3u8", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
```

Comment: @workplaylifecycle is it clear enough? did you get the task completed?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question, but the easiest solution for you might be using the `produces` argument for the mapping annotation:

```java
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/live/timeshift.m3u8", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl")
public String playbackLive(@RequestParam(value = "delay") Integer delay) {
    ....
}
```

Unless you need to dynamically assign the content type of the response, I find this way the most simple.

Comment: amazing... worked, except final output is `Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;charset=UTF-8`, is there anyway only output `Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl`

Comment: @workplaylifecycle Take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32586421/how-to-remove-charset-utf-8-in-a-content-type-header-generated-by-spring-boot. You need to set `spring.http.encoding.force=true` in your application.properties.